# How to trust that a cookie sent back to the server in a subsequent request has not expired?

Tags: security, cookies, browser, browser-security

Expiration is an attribute of cookie. Attributes are not sent back to the server upon subsequent requests. A well-behaved browser will not send an expired cookie, but a malicious browser may ignore the expiration and send the cookie anyway. How can the server tell if the browser is actually honoring the expiration date it originally sent as an attribute of the cookie?

Is it as simple as storing the expiration date *inside* the cookie? Then, if the cookie is signed, the browser can trust that value and check it against its own clock.

Comment: Interesting question - but I think the answer is simply that you, the server, are responsible for being able to handle expired cookies properly (e.g. by displaying a "session has expired" message etc.) Even a benign client might accidentally send an expired cookie, e.g. when the system clock is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEVER. TRUST. USER. INPUT.

By USER, consider anything external to your application.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Don't_trust_user_input

For your particular case, yes, you can add a timestamp to the content of the cookie and sign that content, then check it serverside.

For example using https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php

Comment: I agree, but the question is about *how* the server can verify cookie validity, not whether it should trust the browser.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian As I say, you can, yourself, sign the cookie. Do you need more details about that?